# Is there any way to read a member from a list based on its content?

Tags: python, list

I am a beginner in python trying to make a chatbot for a project in college. We just started this year and our professor asked us to do one, so I am trying to brainstorm ways that I can implement into my project.
I learned about the Wikipedia module and I would like to use it to answer basic "what is X" and "who is Y" questions.
I was planning to do so by telling the user to input a question, then splitting the question by word and storing each word in a list. Then I wanted the program to compare those words to words in a "keyword list" where if certain words matched the bot would print out a response.

I wanted to make it so the bot knew that after the word "what"(or "who") in the question there might exist a word that is important to the question, and I wanted it to put that word through the Wikipedia summary method.

I was trying something like this:

```
def storeInput():
    question = input("Ask me a question! No typos please tho.")
    words = question.split()
    return words

def not_understand():
    print("Unfortunately I couldn't understand what you meant to say... could you repeat again? Be careful"
      " with wording.")

def answer_w_questions():
    key=["what", "who"]

    for word in words:
        if word in key:
            print(wikipedia.summary(#important word))
        else:
            not_understand()
```

However as you can see I don't know how I can make the bot pick the correct word to use on the Wikipedia summary. Is there any way I can make it detect the proper word to search, or is my current of thought not efficient for the program?

Comment: Please use snake case for your functions. So not `storeInput` but `store_input`. It's convention in Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the bot knew that after the word "what"(or "who") in the question there might exist a word that is important to the question

There are several ways to do this.

You might also be interested in having a look at [ntlk](https://www.nltk.org/) or [spacy](https://spacy.io/) for tokenization / stemming

### 1. String splitting

The simplest one is to split the string:

```
>>> question = "Who is the president?"
>>> question.lower().split("who")
['', ' is the president?']
```

As you can see, split returns what was before "who" and what comes after it. So `question.lower.split(key)[1]` gives you everything after the keyword.

### 2. Regex

You could also look at regular expressions (regex): https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

### 3. List index

```
>>> question = "Who is the president?"
>>> key = "who"
>>> words = question.lower().split()
>>> key_index = words.index(key)
>>> words
['who', 'is', 'the', 'president?']
>>> key_index  # starts with 0
0
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than `for word in words`, consider using the built-in `enumerate` ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)) function to make your iterator. This will allow you to reference both the `word` (to see if it is a `key`) but also its position within the list. By knowing its position, you can also reference words in positions relative to it.